# Hiding or Removing UIImageView and arrangement (IOS 5)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5.1

I have a UIViewController that I designed in Interface Builder.  near the top of the View it has a UIImageView and then some other Views (Text etc) below.  These are set to anchor to the top of the view.

In code when the view loads I remove the UIImageView in certain circumstances but it still seems to take space or the view's below don't spring up to the top based on their Anchor.

How can I make the Views below move up if the View above is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the frame of the other elements in the view.

in the viewDidLoad method you can use something like that:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   if(imageVisible){
         otherElements.frame = CGRectMake(....);
   }else{
         otherElements.frame = CGRectMake(....);
   }   
}
```

I don't know what is the structure of the view, but you might consider nesting all of the other elements in one view so you could change all the elements positions in one command.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the Android view hierarchies, iOS view hierarchies are all developed in absolute coordinates.  When you say a subview is anchored to the top, that means that if the size of the parent view changes, your view will stay in the same relative position to the top of the screen.

In order to make your views below the image view move up when the image is hidden or removed, you will have to manually arrange them yourself to account for the offset